# What's wrong with linux/ext2_fs.h?

Tags: c, include, compiler-errors, compilation, ext2

cat main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/ext2_fs.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Here is my output...

> gcc main.c  In file included from main.c:3:
>
> /usr/include/linux/ext2_fs.h: In function ‘ext2_mask_flags’:
>
> /usr/include/linux/ext2_fs.h:182: error: ‘FS_DIRSYNC_FL’ undeclared
>   (first use in this function)
>
> /usr/include/linux/ext2_fs.h:182: error: (Each undeclared identifier
>   is reported only once
>
> /usr/include/linux/ext2_fs.h:182: error: for each function it appears
>   in.)
>
> /usr/include/linux/ext2_fs.h:182: error: ‘FS_TOPDIR_FL’ undeclared
>   (first use in this  function)
>
> /usr/include/linux/ext2_fs.h:184: error: ‘FS_NODUMP_FL’ undeclared
>   (first use in this function)
>
> /usr/include/linux/ext2_fs.h:184: error: ‘FS_NOATIME_FL’ undeclared
>   (first use in this function)

If I remove `#include <linux/ext2_fs.h>` the program compiles successfully...

Comment: Amazing what google turns up - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1408802

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `#include <linux/fs.h>`

Comment: Okay, so I added that and it compiles; however, if I add `ext2_super_block sp;` I get `‘ext2_super_block’ undeclared`

Comment: You still have `ext2_fs.h` included? And I think it should be `struct ext2_super_block sp;`

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after typing my comment (Doh!). Compiles wonderfully now thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `#include <linux/fs.h>` before including the `#include <linux/ext2_fs.h>`

Comment: Providing new answers, that provide no new information, to old threads is of little value to future users. ;(

Answer (score 0):

I had no idea, so I put `ext2_fs.h` into Google and [this was the 4th result](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1408802).

The behaviour [seems to be considered a bug](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/74163/).

Comment: Definitely looked, but I guess I didn't use my Google force skillz. Still didn't help too much, compiler won't recognize ext2_super_block

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
```